# Data binding to list and dynamically adding controls using Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `List<Appointment>` where an Appointment is.

```
public class Appointment
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Start { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }
}
```

I want to dynamically add each list item on a separate line on the form like so:

```
item.Title + " between" + item.Start + " and " + item.End;
```

I want to be able to click each item (the text), then with each click it can toggle the colour of the text between red and black (that is, if black it turns red, if red it turns black when you click).

I come from a web background, but I am just struggling with Windows Forms [data binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binding). I've tried with table layout panel but just don't know where to begin with changing the color of an item on click.

PS: If it helps, the number of items in the list will probably not be more than 10.

I've gotten a bit further as per Jamie Ide's comment:

```
    var appts = GetAllCalendarItems();
    foreach (var item in appts)
    {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text = item.Title + " between" + item.Start + " and " + item.End;
        label.Click += new EventHandler(label_Click);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label);
    }

...

private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This is wrong - what goes here??
    ((Label)sender).ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically laying out Windows Forms is a huge pain. I don't have time to code this but the steps are:

- Add FlowLayoutPanel to form as a container
- Look through your Appointments and create label controls for each
- Add the label controls to the panel's Controls collection
- Assign an OnClick handler to each label control to toggle the color

Don't bother with databinding for this.

---

If you haven't changed the label's initial color from the default, this will toggle it:

```
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lbl = (Label)sender;
        var toggle = lbl.ForeColor == SystemColors.ControlText;
        lbl.ForeColor = toggle ? Color.Red : SystemColors.ControlText;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add each text field as a member of a Label or List view item. Then handle the "OnClick" or "SelectedIndexChanged" event. To create an an OnClick event handler double click on the control in the design view. Edit the handler like this:

```
 private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.SelectedItems[0].ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

If you are unsure about event handlers, don't be put off they are quite easy, just look them up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765195/c-sharp-custom-event-handler) perhaps. If the list view is not what you are looking for, try the same approach on a different control.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I can't comment on Jamie's answer, but raklos you can programmatically add the OnClick method by doing:

```
label.Click += new EventHandler(label_Click);
```

Visual Studio should auto-generate the stubs for you when you start typing that out.

Something like this could get you started:

```
private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { ToggleTextColor((Label)sender); }

private void ToggleTextColor(Control control)
{
    var currentColor = control.ForeColor;
    control.ForeColor = currentColor == Color.Red ? Color.Black : Color.Red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat and make create it in a WebBrowserControl.
You will be in familiar ground.
Use ObjectforScripting for WeBbrowser <=> winforms communication.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx

Comment: Isn't that dependent on Internet Explorer?